# Android keyboard closing on input focus

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms

tried to find the topic about what happening in one of my works, but I couldn't.

When the Android user in Chrome tap to fill a input on my form, the Keyboard appears but suddenly closes immediately. Not giving a chance for user start to fill...

URL FOR EXAMPLE:
http://selva.club/agenda/transa-amazonica-%E2%99%A1-jaloo-show-ao-vivo/

VIDEO RECORDING FOR EXAMPLE:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfb9nkgt7e3zm9u/Video%2023-04-17%2013%2054%2035.mov?dl=0

Comment: Have you invoked `blur` event ?

Comment: @Rayon how exactly, mate? Not sure why this is happening, first time seeing this

Answer (score 10):

After a whole day spent... Just realized what it happens... I have on window.resize event, just cleared this one and it stops the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I observed similar behavior when i accidentally updated the innerHTML:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
  <input>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
if(someaction) myform.innerHTML+= "some notice";
```

Here `someaction` effectively destroys and recreates the input and thus closes the virtual keyboard.

`myform.appendChild()` keeps the old input focused